# Why am I getting a wrong output in a console in C#?

Tags: c#, boolean, indexof

Im a begginer in learning C# and I'm trying to write a console app where, if you say a certain food, you're a certain type of animal.

For some reason, I am constantly getting the same output, no matter which food I type (I'm getting the output with the bear).
Only if I write `Pizza`, I will get an output for a sloth animal.

Can somebody please take a look at this and tell me where Im wrong? And even if I choose some random food that `.IndexOf` didnt find, I still get the bear animal!

```
Console.WriteLine("Select your favorite food and Ill tell you what kind of animal you are!");

string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int userInput1 = userInput.IndexOf("Hamburger", 0);
int userInput2 = userInput.IndexOf("Pizza", 0);
int userInput3 = userInput.IndexOf("Tuna salad", 0);
bool hamUserInput1 = Convert.ToBoolean(userInput1);
bool pizzaUserInput2 = Convert.ToBoolean(userInput2);
bool tunaUserInput3 = Convert.ToBoolean(userInput3);

if (hamUserInput1 == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a bear!");
}
else if (pizzaUserInput2 == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a sloth!");
}
else if (tunaUserInput3 == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a fish!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, I can only say that youre a dinosaur!");
}
```

Comment: *`Convert.ToBoolean(userInput1)`* - highly suspect. Just use `if(userInput.Contains("Hamburger"))` etc ... Bearing in mind that C# is case sensitive by default. For case insens, either use `if(userInput.Contains("Hamburger", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` if your version of C# supports it or `if(userInput.IndexOf("hamburger",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)` if it doesn't

Comment: Worthwhile reading: [First look at the VS debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

[`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-indexof(system-string-system-int32)) returns `-1` when the string passed is not a substring.

[`Convert.ToBoolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean?view=net-6.0#system-convert-toboolean(system-int32)) is true when the passed int is not 0.

You can do `userInput1 != -1` but [`String.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains(system-string)) is what you want.

Comment: Im not really sure what youre trying to say, but you are right. I realise that Convert.ToBoolean is giving back true for everything, but zero. Take a look at this snippet below, please. if bool value of hamburger is true, and if userInput of value Hamburger is true, and then if I put userInput == hamburger, and they are both true from the both sides, how does the end result equal not true? so my program found the word Hamburger and i compared it to hamburger which is set to true, and other words were not found, that means everything else must be false and only Hamburger true, so why does it

Comment: ..print out the part with the bear even if i chose some other word. (I listened to your advice, and put everywhere != and now everything prints out properly, but I dont understand why. If Hamburger was found in a string, means its true, and if bool hamburger value is set to true, they give true. but if i use != means they give the opposite, which then would be false, but in that case it properly prints out in the console. why, oh why?

Comment: `hamUserInput1` is `true` only when the word "Hamburger" is at the start of the string.

Comment: *but if i use != means they give the opposite* - because when you use IndexOf and it DOES FIND the string at index 0 (the start) it returns 0, then `Convert.ToBoolean(0)` creates `FALSE`, which means DOES **NOT** FIND, so then when you use `!=` it inverts this to DOES FIND.. Which "makes it look like it works" but only if the "Hamburger" string is at the start.. All in, I know yuou've sweated blood and tears over those lines of code, but theyre confusing and illogical and *should be thrown away*. Use `Contains`, for nice, simple, code that reads like a book, or a recipe

Comment: Never be afraid of throwing code away; just because I pour a lot of time into some of my code doesn't mean it's good. If after some time of writing some awkward complicated thing that just sorta works in most cases, I suddenly think of a really simple, reliable way to do it I have no hesitations about binning the lot and doing it over - not just for my sanity now, but my sanity in 6 months when I'm re-reading something and things "WTH is this? Who wrote this garb.. oh"

Comment: (And heh, yes.. I appreciate the irony of starting out this comment stream by saying "they aren't for enduring conversation..) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method [string.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains(system-string))
For example
`userInput.Contains("Your Food");`

Comment: Do provide some enhanced information; this is a comment at best, and not even as informative as the existing comment that mentions the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var foodAnimals = new string[,] { { "Hamburger", "bear" }, 
                        { "Piza", "sloth" }, { "Tuna Salad", "fish"} };

    Console.WriteLine("Select your favorite food and Ill tell you what kind of animal you are!");

    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    var animal = "dinosaur";
    for (var i = 0; i < foodAnimals.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        if (userInput.ToLower().Contains(foodAnimals[i, 0].ToLower()))
        {
            animal = foodAnimals[i, 1];
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a {animal}!");
```

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason, I am constantly getting the same output, no matter which food I type (I'm getting the output with the bear). Only if I write Pizza, I will get an output for a sloth animal.

> Can somebody please take a look at this and tell me where Im wrong? And even if I choose some random food that .IndexOf didnt find, I still get the bear animal!

Well, let's try it and see what happens:

#### User types "Hamburger"

I'll replace the method calls with just straight values

```
string userInput = "Hamburger"; //Imagine they type Hamburger
int userInput1 = 0;             //Hamburger found at 0 - userInput.IndexOf("Hamburger", 0);
int userInput2 = -1;            //Pizza not found - userInput.IndexOf("Pizza", 0); 
int userInput3 = -1;            //Tuna salad not found - userInput.IndexOf("Tuna salad", 0);
bool hamUserInput1 = false;     //0 converted to boolean is False - Convert.ToBoolean(userInput1);
bool pizzaUserInput2 = true     //-1 converted to boolean is True -Convert.ToBoolean(userInput2);
bool tunaUserInput3 = true      //-1 converted to boolean is True -Convert.ToBoolean(userInput3);

if (false /*hamUserInput1*/ == true)       //NOT DONE, false is not equal to true
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a bear!");
}
else if (true /*pizzaUserInput2*/ == true) //DONE
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a sloth!");
}
```

We don't need to go any further; we found that when we type Hamburger, you're a sloth!

#### User types "Pizza"

Round 2, here we go!

```
string userInput = "Pizza";     //Imagine they type Pizza
int userInput1 = -1;            //Hamburger not found - userInput.IndexOf("Hamburger", 0);
int userInput2 = 0;             //Pizza found at 0 - userInput.IndexOf("Pizza", 0); 
int userInput3 = -1;            //Tuna salad not found - userInput.IndexOf("Tuna salad", 0);
bool hamUserInput1 = true;      //-1 converted to boolean is True - Convert.ToBoolean(userInput1);
bool pizzaUserInput2 = true     //0 converted to boolean is False -Convert.ToBoolean(userInput2);
bool tunaUserInput3 = true      //-1 converted to boolean is True -Convert.ToBoolean(userInput3);

if (true /*hamUserInput1*/ == true)       //DONE
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a bear!");
}
```

We don't need to go any further; we found that when we type Pizza, you're a bear!

#### User types "ASDF"

Round 3, here we go!

```
string userInput = "ASDF";      //Imagine they type ASDF
int userInput1 = -1;            //Hamburger not found - userInput.IndexOf("Hamburger", 0);
int userInput2 = -1;            //Pizza not found - userInput.IndexOf("Pizza", 0); 
int userInput3 = -1;            //Tuna salad not found - userInput.IndexOf("Tuna salad", 0);
bool hamUserInput1 = true;      //-1 converted to boolean is True - Convert.ToBoolean(userInput1);
bool pizzaUserInput2 = true     //-1 converted to boolean is True-Convert.ToBoolean(userInput2);
bool tunaUserInput3 = true      //-1 converted to boolean is True -Convert.ToBoolean(userInput3);

if (true /*hamUserInput1*/ == true)       //DONE
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, youre a bear!");
}
```

We don't need to go any further; we found that when we type ASDF, you're a bear!

---

This is the kind of debugging you do with the VS Debugger. You click a line, you press F9, you press Play..

..then the code stops on that line with the red dot and you can press F10 or F11 to advance it (stepping over or into methods respectively - step over *stil lruns a method* it just doesn't step into it (can be very tedious if you step into all the time))

You can point to any in-scope variables in the code and see their values at any time

You would see this process; type something, watch the values

---

Straight up, `Convert.ToBoolean` of an IndexOf is a *bad idea*.

- If the IndexOf returns -1 meaning "not found", the ToBoolean makes it `true` as if it "was found"
- If IndexOf returns 0 meaning "found at the start", Convert makes this "not found"
- If IndexOf returns 1+ meaning "found somewhere in the middle", Convert makes this "was found"

So it works some times, but not others - it's terrible, unreliable code. Chuck it away

Look how nice this is:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (userInput.Contains("Hamburger")){
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose Hamburger as your food, you're a bear!");

} else if (userInput.Contains("Pizza")){{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose Pizza as your food, you're a sloth!");
}
else if (userInput.Contains("Tuna salad")){
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose Tuna salad as your food, you're a fish!");
}
else{
    Console.WriteLine($"Since you chose {userInput} as your food, I can only say that you're a dinosaur!");
}
```

Comment: Your reply is incredibly helpful and thank you very much for putting thought into it for my begginer brain!